# How to launch function one time when I have a recurrent call in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I want to call my function just one time when my variable returns true, even if I have 20xtrue.
Currently I am listening to a variable from `didChangeDependencies()` so I have a continue stream of data, and when my variable is true, I have some true that call my function. I am trying to call my function only for the first true. To fix it a little, I have added a tempo after true to switch to false after some milliseconds but it's ugly, and some time my function doesn't see the true...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should put this into a for loop, so you can exit/break the loop when the value is true. Simplified version of this is the following:

```
for(var item in items){
  if(item.status){ // true
    //notify or do the thing you want to do
    break;
  }
}

note: this cannot be achieved with a forEach. It has to be a for loop to do this.
```

Is this what you want? Otherwise please try to elaborate on your problem.